# How to solve this Differential equation(Integrating-factor)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Can someone help me with this differential equation.

$$y\tan(x) + \frac{e^{xy}}{\cos^2(x)} + x\tan(x)y' = 0$$

I guess it should be used integrating-factor but I can't solve it.

Comment: No, equation is correct :)

Comment: I have edited your post. Please let me know if it all looks good

Comment: Yes, it looks good. Thanks.

Comment: Integrating factor $e^{-xy}\cot x$.

Comment: Thanks. It works.